How to copy a table in postgres from cmd
I have a postgres table with dbeaver that I can export using
copy "Dibbs".macro
to 'C:\Users\yuju\SQL_Data\PanelBidList.csv'
with delimiter ',' csv header;

I was making a batch that does the same while updating the table like
psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost -d postgres -a -f C:\Users\yuju\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6\General\Scripts\test.sql

When I do it through dbeaver, I get the csv file perfect but when I use the batch I get an error saying

ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xef 0xbf 0xbd in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"

What is the best way to fix this problem?

Read Character set conversion server/client.

COPY has an ENCODING option.
